# replace ENV values of Dockerfile at runtime

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I've got a similar problem. My Dockerfile

```
FROM busybox

ENV foo dev
ENV bar xyz

COPY run.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/run.sh"]
```

the run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $foo $bar
```

After building I run: `docker run example --env "foo=Hallo Welt"` but I get the output: `dev xyz`

So somehow docker doesn't replace my ENV values. What am I making wrong?

Comment: You need to put `--env` before the image name `example`.  (Try adding `echo command line args: "$@"` to your script and see what happens.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All arguments specified after the name of the image are treated as input arguments to the container, as opposed to flags to Docker.

Move the name of the image at the end of the command:

```
$ docker run --env "foo=Hallo Welt" example
Hallo Welt xyz
```